# Javascript: unable to get height of newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

After updating the DOM with a new element (e.i. body.append(html)), I cannot immediately get the height of the newly updated element (e.g. body.height()). A partial fix is setting a time interval and getting the height at the end of time interval (setTimeout("alert(body.height)", 500)).

Any better ideas? Like a callback after DOM completely updates? Thanks.

Edit: 
This only happens when there is a lot going on in the background (i.e. when page first loads). It would seem like the page update is almost instantaneous if nothing else is being processed. What I need is a callback, or an indicator of when the DOM is reformed!

Edit: 
The problem is from the browser being 'distracted' by other processes, which makes the browser unable to update immediately after the append of the element. How do I fix this?

Comment: By any chance are you appending the HTML in an asynchronous call, like an ajax query?

Comment: Ｉｔ＇ｓ　ｄｉｆｆｉｃｕｌｔ　ｔｏ　ｒｅｃｒｅａｔｅ　ｔｈｅ　ｐｒｏｂｌｅｍ　ｒｉｇｈｔ　ｎｏｗ　ａｓ　ｉｔ　ｉｓ　ｃａｕｓｅｄ　ｂｙ　ｔｈｅ　ｅｎｔｉｒｅ　ｐａｇｅ　ｌｏａｄｉｎg (I am still using lamp)

Answer (score 1):

The timeout method works because the rendering engine is given a chance to display the new element there by giving it a change to render it and thus assigning it a height.

You can set the timeout to 0 and still have the same effect.

Comment: no, actually there is a threshold. For example, timeout = 500 might work, while 200 won't.

Comment: tested in firefox, chrome, and ie

Comment: Ignore my comment about setting the timeout to 0. The rest still applies.

Comment: Can you think of a more 'precise' solution? Can I detect when the rendering engine is done processing the height of the new element?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/b7HCw/5/) for me.

In the jsfiddle demo I put the next code:

```
$(function(){
    var jTest = $('#test');

    console.log('The height:',jTest.innerHeight(),jTest.height()); //Show me 'The height: 20 20'

    jTest.append('<div><br/>How are you?</div>');
    console.log('The height:',jTest.innerHeight(),jTest.height()); //Show me 'The height: 60 60'

});
```

Unless you mean javascript only solution or put a jsFiddle demo to show your error.

Comment: It works because there is nothing else being processed so the browser updates almost immediately. However, if the browser is slowed down by other processes, this will not work

Comment: What kind of process? If is ajax I recomend to you call a function at the end of the request (using `$.ajax()`), otherwise you could do a `setTimeOut` to see if the process has been ended and then call your function to see the height.